# Not letting the user click anymore on a table's td element when something happens

Tags: javascript

I have a table with multiple td elements, and this is what I did so I make them do something when I click on each td element:

```
   window.onload = function(){



           var all = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
              all[i].onclick = inputClickHandler;    
            }
        };


       var max = 2, highlighted = 0;var results = [2];var sum = 0, count = 0;

    function inputClickHandler(e){

      e = e||window.event;
      var tdElm = e.target||e.srcElement;
        results = tdElm.innerHTML;
      if(tdElm.style.borderColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
        highlighted--
        count--;
        tdElm.style.borderColor = '#000000';
      } else if (highlighted < max){
        highlighted++
        count++;
        tdElm.style.borderColor = '#FF0000';

         if(count==1){
           //numArr.push(results);
           numArr[0]= results;
         }else
           //numArr.push(results);
           numArr[1]=results;
        if(count==2){
          sum = +numArr[0] + +numArr[1];
          }else
            sum = 0;
        if(sum==fNum){
          max +=2;
          count = 0;
          numArr = [];
          score += 1;
          scoreGet.innerHTML = (score);
        }
```

I want that when the count is 2 and the sum is equal to fNum to do something with the last 2 td's which I selected.
I tried adding this to the last if (if sum==fNum):

```
 }else{
      count = 0;
      highlighted = 0;
      sum = 0;
      tdElm.style.borderColor = '#000000';
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Instead it let's me select how many td's I want, even if the sum of the 2 is equal to fNum . 
And one more thing. I want that if I select 2 td's in a row, and the sum is equal to fNum to not let me click on either of them again.
Appreciate any help :) I'm new to javascript. I would want it in javascript, not in jQuery if possible.
Thank you!

Comment: Roland, is this all of the code?  It appears to be incomplete — leastaways, your curly braces don't balance.  So if this is all the code, I'd expect to see a lot of errors for it in the browser's JavaScript console, and I'd expect that the browser thinks there's a lot more wrong with it than just that condition.  **Pro tip**: The formatting of this code is all over the place, and makes it very hard to read. One reason for formatting code neatly is so that when you have to ask others why it's not working, they can easily read it and help you.

Comment: This isn't all of the code. Just the eventListener part which allows me to click on the td elements of the table

Comment: I've tried a couple times now to figure out what you were trying to do and answer this, but to be honest, the question is so fuzzy and imprecise, and the code is such a mess, that it's almost beyond fixing.  I'd suggest you just study more JavaScript and then rethink the design.  What you're trying to do — as far as I can guess from the question, and it's not obvious — is (probably) doable, but this is just not the way to go about it.